# I keep getting an error with cocoa pods and installing fireBase

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, debugging, cocoapods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbJhL.jpg)

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Crystal' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Crystal
  # add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage


end


//error yanesrosenskrabe@MacBook-Pro-de-Yanes Crystal % pod install
Ignoring ffi-1.13.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.13.1

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: unterminated string meets end of file
/Users/yanesrosenskrabe/Downloads/Crystal/Podfile:16: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting end.

 #  from /Users/yanesrosenskrabe/Downloads/Crystal/Podfile:16
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >  end 
 #  -------------------------------------------
yanesrosenskrabe@MacBook-Pro-de-Yanes Crystal %
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as code and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your podFile

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage
```

is missing an ending quote

```
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
```

It's also a good idea to edit your podfile with Cocoapods app or the pico editor in terminal so you don't accidentally add any oddball or invisible characters.